# Google Cloud SDK installation failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk

I am trying to install google cloud SDK on my windows 10 enterprise

I get an error stating that one of the components are unknown (kuberun)

Here is the full detail:

> Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK Downloading
> Google Cloud SDK core. Extracting Google Cloud SDK core. Create Google
> Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
> SDK\cloud_env.bat Installing components. '""C:\Program' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file. '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file. Welcome to the
> Google Cloud SDK! Active code page: 65001 ERROR:
> (gcloud.components.update) The following components are unknown
> [kuberun]. This will install all the core command line tools necessary
> for working with the Google Cloud Platform. Active code page: 437
> Failed to install.

Comment: Which SDK version? What is the method you are installing (EXE or PowerShell, Only me or All users, etc.)? My guess is that you either have a syntax error with your PATH variable or your PATH is full and another entry cannot be added.

Comment: Start by uninstalling the SDK, review/fix  your PATH statement and then reboot your system. Try installing again.

Comment: I just downloaded EXE file from the google cloud page. I have tried Only Me and All users,  but same result

Comment: Do you mean uninstalling my windows SDK add on?

Comment: Yes, uninstall the Google Cloud SDK if it is installed/partially installed.

Comment: There is no existing full/partial installation of Google Cloud SDK

Comment: Please do not use comments for chat. Reread my first comment, check the PATH and update your question.

Comment: It's not very helpful to first say "Update your PATH" (with what?) and secondly  to abruptly state that they shouldnt answer your comment. I too have this issue - tried amending my path by adding python3 explicity. The troubleshooting page recommends making sure `find` is accfessible from the prompt - which it is.

Comment: A [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/170709336) was reported to the public issue tracker and the root cause of the issue was some conflict with the installed Python and the bundled Python. Could you use the bundled Python and try to install the Cloud SDK? If the issue still persists, I recommend to report it to the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102) so that we would be able to further investigate it.

Comment: Thanks, @katayoon, I would be concerned if the 'bundled" python would try to overwrite the existing python installation

Comment: Hi, I just stumbled across the same error. It worked when I checked to install the Bundled python. I also have a local Python 3.7 install so I didn't want to clutter things up, so this is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Windows Installer, try one from this link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives

Make sure you choose the right one (based on your CPU Architecture) and I suggest to use bundled python version and get going.